# List of users who visited node

Tags: nodes

Is there any module available, with a functionality to show list of users who have visited certain nodes?

I've searched for module like this but haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module for this. Here is a quote about it (from its project page, bold markup added here):

> ... allows to count node views. Unlike statistics module, this module **records each view of node with user uid and timestamp**. So now you can know **how many times a user viewed node by day, week, month and etc**.
>
> This module is **integrated with Views module**. You can use it to create different statistics pages, output new not viewed nodes for user and many more.

By using this module, and to the extend it should be needed, you can then further refine / extend what you get (out-of-the-box) from this module via a custom module(s) and/or view(s).

Comment: Ok I've installed this module but it only shows title of the node and counter of views, there is no info about users, should i add some fields to the view?

Answer (score 1):

I think this [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) contrib module helps you.

[Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount)

> Node View Count module allows to count node views. Unlike statistics
>   module, this module records each view of node with user uid and
>   timestamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by
>   day, week, month and etc.

Comment: Will this module show me w list of users who visited a node? I can create custom view with this module?

Answer (score 0):

[Recently read](https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read)

> **Recently read** allows site administrators to enable blocks displaying a
>   history of recently read content (nodes) both to anonymous and
>   authenticated users. For logged in users, each user has its own
>   history. For anonymous users, the history is based on sessions. This
>   module may be useful i.e. for displaying recently viewed products on
>   the e-commerce site.
>
> Note about performance: page caching is disabled for pages containing
>   Recently read block and viewed by anonymous users.

OR

[list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal](http://jan.tomka.name/blog/list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal)